# Value of filling the gaps in a proof

Tags: self-learning, learning

I am studying a paper "On Finite Groups with Given Conjugate Types I" recently.
The author uses many words like "obviously", "clearly", "trivially", etc. in his proof. But these "obvious" implications are not so obvious for me.
I always need to spend a lot of time to prove the "obvious"
(if I can prove it).
http://bfhaha.blogspot.tw/2014/06/a-note-on-paper-of-ito-on-finite-groups.html

Question:
Why is there no man who writes a note of the paper to explain the "obvious"?

My guesses are:

1. Mathematicians think that proving a new result is more important than giving  details of the proof.
2. Proving the  "obvious" is a good opportunity for readers to practice.

Answer (score 2):

It is often a good exercise
to fill in these gaps in proofs.

First,
it will greatly increase your understanding
of the subject matter.

Second,
others may have the same problem,
and you might get a publication
showing your work.

Finally,
there might be an error
hidden by the
"obviously" and
"clearly".
Revealing this error
cen be useful in a number of ways:
you might show that
the result is false
by constructing a counterexample,
or you might be able
to fix the error,
either by correcting it
or by adding some additional conditions
that make the error correct.

In any case,
go for it-
fill in the gaps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you recommend that someone get a shave or do you describe how they should cut each hair?

Obviousness is context-dependent, in particular on the expected/intended audience.  I don't need to tell someone *how* to shave, because to anyone I would tell to do so, it's obvious.

Comment: To the downvoter:  There is only one question in the OP (recently edited to): "Why is there no man who writes a note of the paper to explain the 'obvious'?".  I have answered that question.  The other posted answer does not.  (It responds to the numbered items in the OP.)